# Bootstrap modal like behavior in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm handling the image click on an object to display a pop-up box. This is my code.

```
<a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick} data-id={image.id}>
```

This is my handleClick method.

```
 handleClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let mediaId = event.currentTarget.attributes['data-id'].value;
        this.setState({overlay: <Overlay mediaId={mediaId}/>});
      }
```

This is the relevant css

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, #7282fb, #755bf9, #7934f7);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px gray;

}
```

> I want this pop-up to slide into the page from top, something like a
>   bootstrap modal.
>
> Also I want this overlay to go, if I click anywhere outside the box.

How can I achieve this.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#overlays)'s implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use some library to archive desired behavior. There is some for React, can be found by "modal", "overlay" keywords. A lot of alternatives exist. Take a look at https://github.com/fckt/react-layer-stack (check alternatives also https://github.com/fckt/react-layer-stack#alternatives). It solves your case perfectly. Demo and examples - https://fckt.github.io/react-layer-stack/